# Microsoft Sign In with Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I've integrated social logins (Google and Facebook) through [angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) and now finding a way to integrate microsoft based accounts.

Is there a way to integrate Microsoft accounts (hotmail, live, outlook) with Angular?

All searches and examples in the web are mostly specific to Microsoft Azure. Is there any npm library to integrate this? Any ideas?

Comment: Do it in JS way... Or make your own library https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial

Comment: @Sergey, Thanks and will check on this

Comment: @Sergey JS Way, what you meant? Could you please explain?

Comment: For every API that is meant to be used on websites there is a doc on how to use it in JS (JavaScript). Since Angular is just JS framework you are free you to work with plain JS.

Comment: @Sergey, I've figured it out after your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

After Sergey Comment, I've implemented it with [msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal).

Here it is,

```
npm install msal --save
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserAgentApplication } from 'msal'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent 
{
    userData;
    userAgentApplication;

    constructor(private socialAuthService: AuthService) {
        var applicationConfig = {
            clientID: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
        };

        this.userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, null, this.tokenReceivedCallback);
    }

    public tokenReceivedCallback(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
        if (token) {
            this.userData = token;

            console.log("Token: " + token)
        } else {
            console.log(error + ":" + errorDesc);
        }
    }

    public microsoftSignIn() {
        var graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send"];
        let that = this;

        that.userAgentApplication.loginPopup(graphScopes).then(function(idToken) {
            //Login Success
            that.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent(graphScopes).then(function(accessToken) {

                console.log(accessToken)
                //AcquireTokenSilent Success
                var headers = new Headers();
                var bearer = "Bearer " + accessToken;
                headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
                var options = {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: headers
                };
                var graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";

                fetch(graphEndpoint, options)
                    .then(function(response) {

                        response.json().then(function(data) {
                            that.userData = data;

                            console.log(data)
                        })
                    })
            }, function(error) {
                //AcquireTokenSilent Failure, send an interactive request.
                that.userAgentApplication.acquireTokenPopup(graphScopes).then(function(accessToken) {
                    //updateUI();
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            })
        }, function(error) {
            //login failure
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

**login.component.html**

```
{{ userData | json }}

<button (click)="microsoftSignIn()">Sign in with Microsoft</button>
```

Comment: this seems to working, I will try and let you guys know

Answer (score 0):

There is msal-angular library now:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/angular9-sample-app

I've made own implementation of MsalInterceptor to overcome issues with protectedResourceMap.
This is my custom code block:

```
// #region own workaround in order not to put every api endpoint url to settings
if (!scopes && req.url.startsWith(this.settingsService.apiUrl)) {
  scopes = [this.auth.getCurrentConfiguration().auth.clientId];
}
// #endregion

// If there are no scopes set for this request, do nothing.
if (!scopes) {
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

PS: Vote for wildcard in protectedResourceMap https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1776