# Client ID missing when using Microsoft openid in Outlook add-in

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on, outlook-addin, multi-factor-authentication

Added Angualr App to Outlook add-in.

Angular App proceeds with Microsoft login using OpenID as shown below.

```
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
export var _msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
clientId: '', // This is your client ID
authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/', // This is your tenant ID
redirectUri: '', // This is your redirect URI
},
cache: {
  cacheLocation: "localStorage",
  storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
}
};

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
HomeComponent,
],
  imports: [
BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
HttpClientModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }),
MsalModule.forRoot(_msalConfig, {
  popUp: !isIE,
  consentScopes: [
'user.read',
'openid',
'profile',
 ],
 protectedResourceMap: [
['https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me', ['user.read']]
  ],
  extraQueryParameters: {}
})
],
})
```

Even when two-step MFA authentication is attempted, certain user accounts are missing the Client ID.
Error address : https://tokenprovider.termsofuse.identitygovernance.azure.com/

> error:invalid_request error_description:The mandatory 'client_id'
> parameter is missing.

When I looked at the header using developer tools, there was no client ID.

[image]

Is there any workaround when this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any of these are cause. Before that check if, clientId is passed correctly.

Please check the supported account types as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/  Sign in users with work and school accounts or personal Microsoft accounts.And check if users  signing in are using the supported type.

And make sure grant flow used is enabled .

Check the same with v1 end point.

```
protectedResourceMap: [ 

        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']] 

  And see if extra consents are required .
```

References:

1. [microsoft-sign-in-with-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047635/microsoft-sign-in-with-angular/62446391#62446391)
2. [So reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68463499/office-add-in-for-outlook-windows-with-angular-display-dialog-not-working)

Other wise please raise a support ticket for the issue. You can request support request(help+support) from portal and create a new technical request.